# Can I fit a square image to fill bootstrap background image slider without cropping the image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried every combination I've found on SO to try and fix this, but I'm having no luck...so here's my issue.

I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to find the right combination of css (I think this can be done with pure css) to get perfectly square images to FILL the background for a website I'm working on. The square images are scans from a medium format film camera and they don't see to want to fit. However images from digital cameras fit just fine. For the square images it looks like it's cutting off sections from all 4 sides.

Here's the code:

```css
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://testing.bitzer.me/kirstenleah/img/bg.jpg');"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/bg1.jpg');"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

You can see this in action at http://testing.bitzer.me/kirstenleah/index.html

Both images on there are 800x800px and are being cropped to not show the entire image.

I would really appreciate some direction here so that the entire image will show up on the background.

Comment: I suspect that you need rather `background-size: contain;` if you don't need cropping.

Comment: You probably want to link your resources as absolute links, not relative ones. As you might have noticed, your snippet doesn't load anything.

Comment: @c-smile that sorta get's me there, but it repeats the same image 3 times across the screen for some reason...http://testing.bitzer.me/kirstenleah/index.html

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I tried changing to have absolute links, but still not getting anything to load in the snippet :(

Comment: You also need to add `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` as external resources for it to work. Also link any custom `.css` or `.js` files you might have loaded in your page.

Answer (score 1):

You're only able to fill the screen to the size of the browser window, which is a rectangle. So if your image is a square, you're only going to be able to get the top and bottom to meet the edge of the screen, the sides will have a gap. If you stretch the sides to meet horizontally and want to maintain proportion, the top and bottom will cut off - as is happening in your example.

What you need to do is make a compromise. Work with the following:

```
background-size:contain;
          or
background-size:cover;
          or
background-size: auto 100%;
          or
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Try those out and see how they function - make sure to resize the window in and out with each one so you can observe how they work responsively -

If you're wanting to have the image completely cover the screen at ANY size, you can use a media query to switch from **100% auto** to **auto 100%** at the exact point at which the browser window proportions alternate and the other set of dimensions takes precedence.

If you want to clarify your question better and include a jsfiddle, I'll be happy to iron it out for you to see because I know it can sound confusing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the information. If I can't get it working, I'll be sure to throw together a JsFiddle and go from there.

Comment: Here, I put it in codepen for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGELYW


  --  If you clarify exactly what you're asking for, I'll show you the changes on there.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I'll take a look here shortly :)

Answer (score 0):

Last three properties shall do the magic:

```
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```